# ggplot2 usage of free_x causes incorrect graph due to missing data

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, visualization

My data frame has information about a stock along the years.

```
    Date          Adj.Close YEAR
 1 2014-01-21     32.63     2014
 2 2014-01-17     33.40     2014
 3 2014-01-16     32.00     2014
 4 2014-01-15     32.22     2014
 5 2014-01-14     31.10     2014
 6 2014-01-13     30.87     2014
```

in my ggplot2 facet_wrap, I had to add the scales="free_x" in order to show a full view of a year, problem is that 2014 is not over yet (at least at the time of writing this question) and the data is between 01-Jan-2014 until today 22-Jan-2014. The graph is stretched (obviously because of free_x) and I wonder how can I avoid this? How can I show only the right portion of Jan with respect to the other YEARs? I can make the same argument for the first year (starts March 1993).

```
ggplot(stock.data, aes(x=Date, y=Adj.Close)) + 
  geom_line(data=stock.data, aes(x=Date, y=Adj.Close), colour = "blue") + 
  facet_wrap(~ YEAR, ncol=4, scales="free_x")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe add a row corresponding to Dec 31st of that year, but with an NA value?